# Declare a static variable in an enum class

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have an enum for colors. I wish to add a helper method "toRGB()" to the enum class that converts an instance of the enum to an RGB object. As an optimization, I wished to create the dictionary once as a static variable. However, the correct syntax seems to elude me.

Can anyone suggest the right way to do this?

```
from enum import Enum

class RGB:
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        pass

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 0
    GREEN = 1

    __tbl = {
              RED:   RGB(1, 0, 0),
              GREEN: RGB(0, 1, 0)
            }

    def toRGB(self):
        return self.__class__.__tbl[self.value]

c = Color.RED
print(c.toRGB())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(c.toRGB())
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.py", line 17, in toRGB
    return self.__class__.__tbl[self.value]
TypeError: 'Color' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: I realise this is very old, but to answer the actual question. dunderscore variables are ignored. So you can name it `__tbl__`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Non-method attributes become enum members (even `tbl`). You can use a keyword argument instead:

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 0
    GREEN = 1

    def toRGB(self, tbl={
        RED:   RGB(1, 0, 0),
        GREEN: RGB(0, 1, 0)
    }):
        return tbl[self.value]
```

Alternatively, you can define the attribute after class creation:

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 0
    GREEN = 1

    def toRGB(self):
        return self._tbl[self]

Color._tbl = {
    Color.RED:   RGB(1, 0, 0),
    Color.GREEN: RGB(0, 1, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 23):

As of Python 3.7, use the `_ignore_` field: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

```
class Color(Enum):
    _ignore_ = ['_tbl']
    _tbl = {}  # nice for the type checker, but entirely ignored!


Color._tbl = {}  # actually creates the attribute
```

Comment: Note that this unfortunately doesn't work with Pyright. It still thinks `_tbl` is a `Color`, even if you do `_tbl: dict[...] = {}`. In the end I just put `_tbl` in global scope: `_color_tbl: dict[...] = {}; class Color(Enum): ...`

Comment: Documentation states `_tbl` gets removed from class after creation. So how is this helpful?

Comment: @Melendowski `_ignore_` is what gets removed, not `_tbl`

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell from your example if the `0`, `1`, `2`, ..., are meaningful values or just place-holders, but if they are just place-holders then the best solution is to discard them and use the `RGB` values as the `Enum` member value directly:

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1, 0, 0
    GREEN = 0, 1, 0
    BLUE = 0, 0, 1
```

If the `Enum` members have a `value` separate from their `rgb` values you could use the [new aenum library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) and solve the problem like this:

```
from aenum import Enum, NamedTuple

RGB = NamedTuple('RGB', 'r g b')

class Color(Enum, init='value rgb'):
    RED = 1, RGB(1,0,0)
    GREEN = 2, RGB(0,1,0)
    BLUE = 3, RGB(0,0,1)
```

and in use:

```
>>> Color.RED
<Color.RED: 1>

>>> Color.RED.rgb
RGB(r=1, g=0, b=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a type conversion, then you could use the `RGB` class as the enumeration value:

```py
from enum import Enum

class RGB:
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        # Check your inputs
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.r} {self.g} {self.b}"

class Color(Enum):
    RED = RGB(1, 0, 0)
    GREEN = RGB(0, 1, 0)

    def toRGB():
        return c.value

c = Color.RED
print(c.toRGB())
```

You could also skip the `toRGB` helper method and simply write `Color.RED.value`

A different way to implement static class variables for an `Enum` subclass is to use the singleton pattern:

```py
class Color(str, Enum):
    RED = "red"
    GREEN = "green"

    def __new__(cls, value):
        if not hasattr(cls, "instance"):
            cls.__tbl = {"red": RGB(1, 0, 0), "green": RGB(0, 1, 0)}
        obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
        return Enum.__new__(cls, obj)
```

Note that you cannot use instances of the enum like `RED`, `GREEN` etc. inside the definition of `__new__` (they do not exist yet), so I have used string identifiers instead. I would prefer the first solution in general. My code looks like this since it needs to load a large dataset exactly once.