# Add and initilalize an enum class variable in Python

Tags: python, enums

I'm implementing an `enum` `class` and want to retrieve an aggregate information about the `enum` members. Each `enum` represents a breakout board with different number of pins, and I want to get the maximum number of pins over all boards. My approach was to add a class attribute _max_pins which is adjusted during `__init__` of each member.

Problem is, it is not possible to define _max_pins ahead if the members as it would become a member, too. It does not help to define it after the members as then the members cannot access it during their `__init__`
I've looked at [Declare a static variable in an enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003273/declare-a-static-variable-in-an-enum-class) but the table can be set up after `__init__` - that would be possible but would need to scan again all members after their initialization.

```py
class IgelTyp(Enum):
    LED_1 = (24, 1)
    LED_2 = (24, 2)
    LED_3 = (16, 4)

    _max_pin = -1

    def __init__(self, pins, groups):
        if _max_pin < pins//groups:     # gives error
            _max_pin = pins//groups

    @classmethod
    def get_max_pins(cls):
        return cls._max_pin
```

Above code produces `UnboundLocalError: local variable '_max_pin' referenced before assignment`

When I move the assignment of _max_pin in front of the member definition it tells me that `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: ...`

**Edit 1**
Actually, the `TypeError` is raised regardless where I put the assignment within the class.
And when I use `IgelTyp._max_pin = -1` I get a `NameError: name 'IgelTyp' is not defined`

Anyone has an efficient and readable solution?

Comment: Maybe you want `IgelTyp._max_pin` instead.

Comment: I tried, but does not work while initialization of IgelTyp is not done (see edit 1).

Comment: I mean inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: Im not 100% certain, but shouldn't it be `self._max_pin` ...

Comment: @Goyo Unfortunately the same `NameError` is given.

Comment: @Magellan88 would that not make `_max_pin` into an instance attribute instead of a class attribute?

Comment: I'm not really sure that a class attribute exists in python... I would have done a wrapper class, that has a list of breakout boards inside it. Inside that wrapper class you can then keep an instance variable about the number of all pins.

Comment: Wow! Apparently this happens only if you inherit from `Enum`.

Comment: Well,  as explained in the linked answer, non-method class attributes become the enum members and you are not supposed to change them. The error messages are confusing but looking at your code it doesn't look that an `Enum` is what you need.

Comment: Anything that does not start and end with double underscores, single underscores or that is not a descriptor becomes an enum member. You can push your var into one of these exception categories. Names starting and ending with single underscores are reserved for future use in enums. I don't see how one could reasonably make that name a descriptor, but you could name that variable `__max_pin__` and access it via `self.__class__.__max_pin__` in `__init__()`.

Comment: @shmee if you convert that into an answer I would mark it as the accepted solution - it works and is simple.

Comment: @Walter I strongly recommend to go with Ethan's solution. On second thought, creating a dunder name to prevent `max_pin` from becoming a member is not really a good idea. The dunder namespace should remain reserved for special use in the language; something I didn't really think about when I wrote the comment. Considering that Ethan is the principal author of `Enum`, his solution appears to be the intended way to do what you want. Although I don't like how the name he chose for the descriptor clashes with `typing.ClassVar` :D

Comment: @shmee:  I am happy to consider different names.  :-)

Comment: @EthanFurman Personally, I'd have gone for something along the lines of `EnumClassVar` to make the intended purpose more explicit. As an aside, your recent answers on the topic of enums in Python made me take a closer look at that module and helped me to greatly improve my understanding of it. Thanks for sharing your knowledge! Seems like a very thoughtful implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One-off solution:**

Change your `__init__` to directly access the class's dictionary:

```
def __init__(self, pins, groups):
    max_pin = self.__class__.__dict__.get('max_pin', 0)
    self.__class__.max_pin = max(max_pin, pins//groups)
```

Interestingly, you could easily have each LED member store its own `max_pin` by adding this line at the end of `__init__`:

```
    self.max_pin = pins//groups
```

so:

```
>>> IgelTyp.max_pin
24
```

but:

```
>>> IgelType.LED_2.max_pin
12
```

---

---

**Reusable solution**

Create your own class attribute descriptor, and use that to shield `max_pin` from becoming an `IgelTyp` member:

```
class ClassVar:              # add (object) if using Python 2
    "a class variable"

    def __init__(self, value):
        # store initial value
        self.value = value

    def __get__(self, *args):
        # get value in ClassVar instance (only doable because all instances
        # share same value)
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, _, value):
        # save value in ClassVar instance (only doable because all instances
        # share same value)
        self.value = value
```

Descriptors, such as `property` usually store the value on the instance itself so that each instance can have it's own value (such as 24, 12, and 4 from your example); however, since you want to know the maximum number of pins across all instances, we just save that single value on the `ClassVar` instance.

The changes to `IgelTyp`:

```
class IgelTyp(Enum):

    LED_1 = (24, 1)
    LED_2 = (24, 2)
    LED_3 = (16, 4)

    max_pin = ClassVar(0)

    def __init__(self, pins, groups):
        self.max_pin = max(self.max_pin, pins//groups)
```

and in use:

```
>>> IgelTyp.max_pin
24
>>> IgelTyp.LED_2.max_pin
24
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer @Ethan Furman. While it seems a proper and reusable solution, it is overshooting for my one-time occasion of use.

Comment: @Walter:  I added a one-off solution at the top.  Hope that works better for you.

Comment: Thank you for the addition - the one-off solution might not be as clear and straight as the Reusable solution, but it is what I was looking for!